# How can I create an index-teaserJS statistic like Researchgate?

Tags: javascript

On the front page of http://www.researchgate.net/ there are statistics that load the different users. How can I replicate that? What were the tools used to create the index-teaserJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm one of the people who worked on the infographic.

For the graphics part we used Raphael JS (http://raphaeljs.com).
We use YUI3 as our primary JS library, but in this infographic it was only used for minor DOM manipulation stuff.

The chart is, at the very core, based on the Pie Chart example of Raphael: http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html

The reason we used Raphael over solutions like D3 is browser support. Raphael has a good compatibility layer that provides support for old IE versions out of the box. D3, while very nice to work with, is not ideal if you try to support legacy browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> They are using YUI.
>
> A similar implementation of it in D3 Javascript Library can be found here:
>   http://bl.ocks.org/4063423
>
> You can understand how it works by looking at that D3 example.

Source: http://www.quora.com/JavaScript/How-and-with-what-was-the-statistic-analytic-overview-of-ResearchGate-created/answer/Prithviraj-Udaya